# PostgreSQL error: could not connect to database template1: could not connect to server: No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, psql

I need to create database.

First I run: `sudo su - postgres`, then: `createdb test`

And I keep getting this error:

```
createdb: could not connect to database template1: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
```

This is unexpected, I have never encountered any problems with psql, but this time I don't get what is wrong. And there is no external server, I am connected locally.

I am running on Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you recently upgrade? Is postgresql running (ps -ef | grep "post")?

Comment: hello @Patrick this was a fresh install today, the output of `ps -ef | grep "post"` is :
`root      1025  1015  0 11:27 pts/0    00:00:00 sudo su - postgres
root      1026  1025  0 11:27 pts/0    00:00:00 su - postgres
postgres  1027  1026  0 11:27 pts/0    00:00:00 -su
postgres  1031  1027  0 11:29 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
postgres  1032  1027  0 11:29 pts/0    00:00:00 grep post`

Comment: You should check your `pg_hba.conf` file. A local connection over a Unix socket should work, but better make sure. Other issue might be the port, which you can check in the `postgresql.conf` file.

Comment: files like those do not exist on my system

Comment: If those files do not exist, you have not installed Postgres.  [Here's a nice summary of installing Postgres on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL)

Answer (score 14):

The error means that the Postgres server is not running. Try starting it:

```
sudo systemctl start postgresql
```

I believe the service name is postgresql, but if that doesn’t work, try typing

> sudo systemctl start postgres

and pressing tab to auto-complete.

Make sure that the server starts on boot:

> sudo systemctl enable postgresql

Comment: If you're on WSL then use `sudo service postgresql start`

Answer (score 10):

The error message suggests:

> Is the server running locally

and according to the result of `ps -ef | grep "post"` posted in the comments, the answer is a definitive **No**, the [server processes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-ps.html) are not there, the server is not running.

That fact that you write *i have never encountered any problems with psql,* suggests that it was installed and working before, in that case look at the most recent log file inside `/var/log/postgresql` to check for any fatal error message indicating why the server didn't start.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install and run postgreSQL

`createdb -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres testdb password ******`

Comment: createdb: too many command-line arguments (first is "******"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I did the following to get rid of this error:

```
sudo apt remove --purge postgres*
sudo apt remove --purge pg*   #optional
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt clean
```

Then...

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install -y postgresql-10 postgresql-contrib postgresql-client
sudo apt install -y postgresql-server pgadmin4 ] -> this you may need for metasploit
sudo reboot
```

And finally, after checking if Postgresql has been installed, if its down, then do this:

List all the Postgres clusters running on your device:
`pg_lsclusters`

Restart the pg_ctlcluster:
`sudo pg_ctlcluster 10 main start`

Restart PostgreSQL service: 
`sudo service postgresql restart`