# Cant initialize database on google cloud platform

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, bitnami

Here is the database I am trying to install (comes with 4 short instructions very easy to follow): https://github.com/toddwschneider/nyc-taxi-data

I used git clone to bring the repository down to my vm. And next I cd into it and run initialize_database.sh. Here is what happens:

[pic of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqCOa.png)
the password I am trying to use is the one provided by my Bitnami Launchpad, which says the admin user is postgres, but when I work on it it says kzherbert, my google account. I have tried su postgres but its not a user on the server so it doesnt work like that. I can use postgres password for psql -U postgres, which will take me to the psql terminal. Also, I have tried using my google account password as well and it does not work. What really interests me about the picture is where the shapefile is relevant and why it repeats and doesnt allow me to exit

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: postgres   854     1  0 15:38 ? 00:00:00 /opt/bitnami/postgresql/bin/postgres.bin -D /opt/bitnami/postgresql/data postgres 856 854 0 15:38 ? 00:00:00 postgres: checkpointer process postgres 857 854 0 15:38 ? 00:00:00 postgres: writer process postgres 858 854 0 15:38 ? 00:00:00 postgres: wal writer process  postgres 859 854 0 15:38 ? 00:00:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process postgres 860 854 0 15:38 ? 00:00:01 postgres: stats collector process postgres  5949   854  0 17:31 ? 00:00:19 postgres: postgres postgres 73.237.197.185(60776) idle kzherbe+ 6226 5963 0 18:37 pts/0 00:00:00 grep post

Comment: These are the results of running ps -ef | grep "post" to check the server based on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095546/postgresql-weird-error-could-not-connect-to-database-template1-could-not-conne

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the database you are trying to install (Unified New York City Taxi and Uber data) assumes you're installing PostreSQl from scratch instead of using the one included in the Bitnami Image.

The script you're using assumes that the user to connect the database is the same that the System User you're using to connect to your server via SSH (kzherbert in your case). However, the password you're trying to use is the one for the user **postgres**.

You need to connect to PG using the password Google provided you and the user **postgres** and the create an user **kzherbert** with the password you desire.